# Ruby array to js array in .js.erb file on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to turn a ruby array into a js array in a js.erb file. I've checked all questions on this in stack overflow but it isn't working for me.

Here is the function

```
  function c(c) {
   js_array = <%= raw @keys.to_json %>;
   b.selection.remove(), b.html.insert('js_array[0]');
    }
```

It throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`

Im still learning js so im not sure what is going wrong here

The ruby @keys array defiantly has data in it because I'm printing that on the same page.

And if i change the array to `js_array = ['gwfe', 'efw', 'efwe'];` it works fine. This makes me believe something is going wrong when trying to convert the ruby array into a js array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you are gettings @keys data from db or local. Could you try [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) to pass the values from ruby to js. Here is the railscast tutorial for the same: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

And see, if that works.

Let me know.

Comment: Changed it to `js_array = <%=raw @keys.to_a%>;` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you, pass me the print output for @keys.to_a and try removing raw from the print?

Comment: in ruby `@keys` and `@keys.to_a` both give ["king", "juice", "sausage"]

Comment: Hmm, that is weird! :(. Well, a cheeky workaround would be to place the js-array in a hidden div and pick that value up from the div and process it in js. I know, these are lot of steps, but for the time being. Till we find out, why :)

Comment: Could you try this and see this as well `js_array = <%=escape_javascript @keys.to_json %>` ?

Comment: ruby output gives this `[\"king\",\"juice\",\"sasauge\"]` in the js.erb gives undefined method `escape_javascript'

Comment: The array is made from the db. Could i just make the array by calling to the db in js? or are there security flaws. I'm not sure how this would be done in js. here is my call to make the keys variable in ruby `@keys = CategoryItemKey.where(category_id: @category.id).pluck(:name)`

Comment: Well, that is an extra step which I feel is un-necessary. Can you move the js function from erb file to your rails view and see how it goes? The one which contains escape js.

Comment: Might as well, look into this as well. http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the gon gem from the railscast video. That looks like a possible solution. I'll come back with how i went!

Comment: The gon gem from the railscast did the job! add it to your answer and ill give the answer to you! Thanks

Comment: Thats great! I have added it to answer :)

Answer (score 2):

After converting the array to JSON, you just need to mark it as HTML safe so it will render Javascript code.

This will do the trick:

```
<%= @keys.to_json.html_safe %>
```